# System.NotSupportedException when creating a reversed list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to return a list of status updates, that's ordered by inserted date, in a descending order. This list is displayed in a partial view, so I'm unable to use the controller to sort the list. The solution was to create a Service class that includes this code:

```
var StatusResult = (from status in db.UserStatuses
                    orderby status.DateInserted
                    select status).Reverse().ToList();
return StatusResult;
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Project.Models.UserStatus] Reverse[UserStatus](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Project.Models.UserStatus])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF doesn't know how to tell SQL Server to reverse the results of a query, which is why your query is failing when it executes. Although it is possible, the better way to do it is to simply ask for the query results sorted in descending order:

```
var StatusResult = (from status in db.UserStatuses
                    orderby status.DateInserted descending
                    select status).ToList();
return StatusResult;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I wasn't aware that I could write "descending" after DateInserted

Answer (score 3):

`Reverse()` is applied to the `IQueryable<UserStatus>` and attempted to be translated to SQL by the Entity Framework query provider - and [it isn't supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx).

To solve the immediate problem, you'd make sure this happens in memory by moving to `IEnumerable<UserStatus>` first:

```
var statusResult = (from status in db.UserStatuses
                    orderby status.DateInserted
                    select status).AsEnumerable().Reverse().ToList();
```

However, it would make more sense to just order by descending instead:

```
var statusResult = (from status in db.UserStatuses
                    orderby status.DateInserted descending
                    select status).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks allot. I'm gonna use the descending method.

Comment: That would be the best solution as the sort will be executed by the SQL database rather than in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Simply LINQ to Entities does not support Reverse method. As pointed out here:
[Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550.aspx).
You could just first save it to a List() and then reverse it.