# how to change OrderBy direction of IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql-order-by, iqueryable

I have some function (X) which return IQueryable with "OrderBy(x => x.Name)".
I want to use X function in new code, but in this code there is parameter which determine the order (asc/desc).

I prefer not to change (X) since it used in multiple places already.

there is option to get X(), then cancel it's "OrderBy", and apply new order?

(now it throws exception, since it is like Y.OrderBy(a => a.Name).OrderByDescending(a => a.Name))

"A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.\r\nStatement(s) could not be prepared."

Comment: I think you need to write two branches, one with orderby the other with orderbydescending. I wish I knew a more elegant solution..

Comment: What exception do you get in the last case? That should be sub-optimal but still work AFAICT.

Comment: @JonHanna the exception is '"A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.\r\nStatement(s) could not be prepared."

Comment: Ah. I suppose that makes sense. I think I'd just make a localised change to the method then, using a default so that the other callers don't have to be updated.

Comment: @JonHanna in EF 6 it works fine with multiple orderby, so you are partially correct. Depends on provider I think.

Comment: @Evk yeah, it's one of those things where the mapping between what is valid linq and valid SQL needs a catch for the given case.

Comment: @Evk, yes, in this case it's nhibernate

Answer (score 1):

use

```
public void x(string order = string.empty)
{
  Y.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
  if (order == "desc")
  {
    Y = Y.Reverse();
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple if it works, but some query providers [might](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx) not [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156183/system-notsupportedexception-when-creating-a-reversed-list) it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to wiggle Expression object of IOrderedQueryable that your method is actually returning (am I wrong?) but so far no luck, and I can't see the option to manipulate System.Linq.Expression or System.Linq.EnumerableQuery easy enough to use it instead of changing X() method.

IMHO, you should choose from:

- create somes kind of wrapper method using the Reverse() (@Eric Lizotte answer) or OrderByDescending() - it will be less time consuming I guess but for grouping, filtering etc. you will have to create brand new function.
- remove OrderBy() from X() function body, and modify your old code - returning non-ordered result will give you more flexibility and opportunity to do what you want to do with the result via linq expressions in each scenario that you'll came across.

Can you clarify for me if you're talking about "function" you have in mind a sql function that is mapped via ORM (eg. Entity Framework) in your application or just a ordinary method which is using your custom provider to return IQueryable?